# How to animate item across a grid cell?

Tags: c#, uwp

[image]

So I have this control where the user can choose different period's of time.

Like the newer navigation control provided by the `SDK`, I would like the highlighted purple line to animate to the chosen period picked by the user.

The purple line is just a rectangle in a `Grid cell` and when the user clicks one of the periods, the `event handler` simply changes the `cell` the rectangle resides.

My original solution was to calculate the `x` and `y` positions of the `grid cells` using their width and height. Then just create a basic animation from and to that position but it seems like a messy solution to a simple animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using animation to change the rectangle's `(Grid.Column)` value would be better. You could use [DiscreteObjectKeyFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.DiscreteObjectKeyFrame) class.

I just made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Height="50">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="All" Grid.Column="0" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Year" Grid.Column="1" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Month" Grid.Column="2" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Week" Grid.Column="3" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Day" Grid.Column="4" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"></TextBlock>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Height="5" Fill="Purple" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        if (textBlock!= null)
        {
            int column = Grid.GetColumn(textBlock);
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            DiscreteObjectKeyFrame discreteObjectKeyFrame = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame();
            discreteObjectKeyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0));
            discreteObjectKeyFrame.Value = column;
            objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(discreteObjectKeyFrame);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames, "(Grid.Column)");
            Storyboard.SetTarget(objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames, rect);
            storyboard.Children.Add(objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm just getting into UWP so I'm still trying to wrap my head around it, when I get home I'll definitely try your solution!